# How do I stream multiple web cams on a website?

Tags: streaming, camera

A client has asked about designing a site that might have up to 200 live web cams placed in different places around the country streaming live on the website. What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Would all these cams need to be (a) Displayed as a live stream/updated stills (b) how many cams need to be displayed at any one time?

Answer (score 1):

For live video streaming you would typically use a product like [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) (or an open source clone like [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5)). Because of the number of live streams (approx 60Mbps inbound) you are likely to need several feed servers to accept the live streams from the cameras, which then distribute the video to enough front end streaming servers to support your expected usage.

This is a complex (and expensive) arrangement, you might also want to look at using a content delivery network like [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com) or [Limelight](http://www.limelightnetworks.com/) for this.